# python turtle no attribute go to

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

hey guys im new to python and have been trying to design a maze using turtle and i have been facing this error of : `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_goto'`. i was able to add the walls of the maze but when i tried to add the ending position of the maze i was hit with this error. i was able to create a class for End point. Any help would be appreciated!

the error of code is in this line:

```py
if character == "s":
    End.goto(screen_x,screen_y)
    End.stamp()
```

Code:

```
import turtle
 
wn =  turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("A Maze Game")
wn.setup(700,700)
 
class Pen(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
        
class End(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("green")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
 
levels = [""]
 
# XXXXXXXXXXXX
# X...X..X..eX
# X.X....X.XXX
# X..X.X.X.X.X
# XX.XXX.X...X
# X........X.X
# XsXX...X...X
# XXXXXXXXXXXX    
    
level_1 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X   X  X  eX",
"X X    X XXX",
"X  X X X X X",
"XX XXX X   X",
"X        X X",
"XsXX   X   X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX"
]
 
 
levels.append(level_1)
 
def setup_maze(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            character = level [y] [x]
            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)
           
           
            if character == "X":
                pen.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                pen.stamp()
                
            if character == "s":
                End.goto(screen_x,screen_y)
                End.stamp()
 
 
pen = Pen()
 
setup_maze(levels[1])
 
while True:
    pass
```

Comment: `End` isn't a turtle, it's a customized *class* that extends the behavior of the standard turtle class.  You have to create an instance of this class before any of the standard turtle methods are applicable; you did this with the `Pen` class (by writing `pen = Pen()`), but for some reason you didn't do the same with `End`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy fix:
Notice how you've define the `pen` variable to be a `Pen` class object, and put the object intothe conditions.
But for the `End` class, you've *directly* put it into the condition.

Calling `pen.goto` in your case is using the `goto` function as a bound function, the equivalent of `Pen().goto`.
When you've called `End.goto`, you are using the `goto` function as an *unbound* function, henc it will not be able to access any of the `self` variables.

Simply add a `end = End()`, and in the nested `for` loop use `end.goto` instead of `End.goto`.

Code:

```
import turtle
 
wn =  turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("A Maze Game")
wn.setup(700,700)
 
class Pen(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
        
class End(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("green")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
 
levels = [""]
 
level_1 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X   X  X  eX",
"X X    X XXX",
"X  X X X X X",
"XX XXX X   X",
"X        X X",
"XsXX   X   X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX"
]
 
levels.append(level_1)
 
def setup_maze(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            character = level [y] [x]
            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)
            if character == "X":
                pen.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                pen.stamp()
            if character == "s":
                end.goto(screen_x,screen_y)
                end.stamp()

 
pen = Pen()
end = End()
 
setup_maze(levels[1])
 
while True:
    pass
```

Output:

[image]